# How to retrigger GitHub PR build in Jenkins multibranch pipeline with comment?

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I'm evaluating multibranch pipelines. I created a repo, with a jenkinsfile. The branches were detected, builds were triggered on PR.

Now I'd like to rebuild on command via a comment on the GitHub PR, I installed the [Multibranch Scan Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multibranch+Scan+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin) and for now set the regex to `.*`.

When commenting, in the jenkins log, I get 2 lines:

```
2019-11-25 16:30:37.128+0000 [id=1503]  INFO    c.i.j.p.m.ComputedFolderWebHookRequestReceiver#doInvoke: Triggering FMS
2019-11-25 16:30:39.712+0000 [id=1587]  INFO    j.b.MultiBranchProject$BranchIndexing#run: FMS #20191125.163037 branch indexing action completed: SUCCESS in 2.5 sec
```

Great, it seems that the repository was scanned but it doesn't start a new build, I guess because it doesn't detect a modification.

Any idea how to do or if it's actually possible?

Comment: I would also like to know.

Answer (score 3):

You can trigger a multibranch pipeline build in Jenkins by using the [GitHub PR Comment Build Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-pr-comment-build-plugin/):

> This plugin listens for comments on pull requests and will trigger a
> GitHub multibranch job if a comment body matches the configured value,
> such as "rerun the build". This is implemented as a branch property on
> multibranch jobs.
>
> To enable this behavior, simply add one or more of the branch
> properties from this plugin to the multibranch job and configure the
> regular expression to match against the comment body.
> [image: Jenkin]

You also need to configure the GitHub webhook to fire on the Pull Request comment, which it sounds like you've already done.

Comment: Does this works with Jenkins Job DSL?How to use with scripted pipeline?..I would like to retrigger a pipeline job via Pull request comment